# A Markov process which is not strong Markov process (follow up 2)

Tags: stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, markov-process

In https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43833/a-markov-process-which-is-not-a-strong-markov-process

George Lowther's example:
"Consider the following continuous Markov process $X$, starting from position $x$:

If $x = 0$ then $X_t = 0$ for all times.

If $x \neq 0$ then $X_t$ is a standard Brownian motion starting from $x$.
This is not strong Markov (look at times at which it hits zero)."

I don't get it, why this is not a strong Markov process?  Seems to me, $X_{T+t}$ has the simple $\delta$-transition, just like $X_t$ (if starts from $0$).

Since several experts are involved in that post, and they seem to agree this is a valid example, I must have missed something. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that this example IS a strong Markov, but $X_{T+t}-X_T$ does not has the same law as $X_t$, so likely, this example was designed to address another common misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T:=\inf\{t:X_t=0\}$, and suppose that  $X_0=x\not=0$. Fix $t>0$. Then $\Bbb P^x[X_t=0]=0$ because $X_t\sim\mathscr N(x,t)$. On the other hand, if $X$ were a strong Markov process, then on the event $\{T<t\}$ we would have $X_t=0$ because the post-$T$ process $\{X_{T+s}:s\ge 0\}$ would start in state $0$, and so stay in state $0$ for all time by the specification of $X$ when $X_0=0$.
Thus, if $X$ were strong Markov then we would have
$$
\Bbb P^x[X_t=0, T<t]=\Bbb P^x[T<t]>0,
$$
 a contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the set up. My understanding of the part 'If $x\neq 0$ then....' means that, $X_t$ is BM  until it hits 0, at which point, it stay at 0. So the distribution of $X_t$ is not normal, but has some mass weight at 0, i.e. $P^x[X_t=0]>0$

Comment: What you describe is simply "absorbed Brownian motion", which is a strong Markov process.  What Geo. Lowther intends (I think) is just regular B.M. (for all time) if started away from $0$, but the constant-at-0 process if started at $0$.

Comment: @ John Dawkins  I see. In that case, the transition function is not time-homogeneous. A separate law for process starting from 0, which is never  applied to the process starting away from 0, only to contradict a different transition when 0 is hitted. Not a very interesting construction, I have to say.

Comment: @Jay.H The transition kernel in George Lowther's example **is** time homogeneous. I guess you mean that it is not spatially homogeneous.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland I guess I understand your point that given the starting point, the t.f. is time homogeneous. But if we stick to the defination of time homogenuity that the t.f.  $p(t,t+\Delta,x,y)$ does not depends on t, then the example is not time homogeneous, because $t=0$ is special.

Comment: @Jay.H Why don't you calculate $p(t,t+\Delta,x,y)$ and see for yourself that it doesn't depend on $t$?

Comment: Hmm..., now I wonder whether the t.f. is well defined, because it also depends on whether$X_0=0$ for $t\ge 0$

Comment: *"we would have $X_t=0$ because the post-$T$ process $\{X_{T+s}:s\ge 0\}$ would start in state $0$"* Why would the post-$T$ process be considered to start in state $0$ and not in whatever state it had for $t=0$?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is quite interesting, and deserves more attention than it 
has been getting. Whether or not a (time homogeneous) Markov process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$
with state space $E$ is strong Markov depends on a precise definition. 
I hope that my explanation below substracts from, rather than adds to, your confusion.

The standard definition of the strong Markov property says that 
for all times $t\geq 0$, all stopping times $T$, and any bounded, measurable
function $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$\mathbb{E}(f(X_{t+T}){\bf 1}_{(T<\infty)}\mid{\cal F}_T)=(p_tf)(X_T){\bf 1}_{(T<\infty)},\tag1$$
almost surely, where $p_t$ is the transition function of the process.

In George Lowther's example the transition function is 
$$p_t(x,\cdot)=N(x,t) \mbox{ for }x\neq0,\quad p_t(0,\cdot)=\delta_0,$$
where $N(x,0)=\delta_x$. The transition function $(p_t)$ satisfies
$$p_tf(x)=\cases{f(0)& $x=0$\\[5pt] b_tf(x)& $x\neq 0$}, $$
where $b_t$ is the usual Brownian transition function. 
This  $(p_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is well-defined and time homogeneous.

To be concrete, suppose that $X_0=1$, so that $X_t=W_t+1$ where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.
Taking the stopping time $T(\omega)=\inf(t\geq 0: X_t(\omega)=0)$ we have
$\mathbb{P}(T<\infty)=1$ and $p_tf(X_T)=p_tf(0)=f(0)$ on the right hand side of (1).
To be dramatic, take $f(x)={\bf 1}_{\{0\}}(x)$ so that the right hand side of (1) equals 1.

However, for $t>0$, the left hand side is 
${1\over \sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y+1) \exp(-y^2/2t)\,dy=0$,
so the strong Markov property fails.  I believe this is the argument that George Lowther had in mind.

---

What is going on and why does the strong Markov property fail? 
By changing the transition function at a single point, we have created a disconnect between the process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and the transition function $(p_t)_{t\geq 0}$.
The process is just a shifted Brownian motion that rolls over the point $\{0\}$ and continues to move like a Brownian motion. In contrast, the transition function suggests that the process should get stuck as soon as it hits the point $\{0\}.$

Note that the usual Brownian transition function $(b_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is also a transition function for the process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$; transition functions **are not unique**.  With respect to $(b_t)_{t\geq 0}$ our process $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ does satisfy (1) and therefore is a strong Markov process.

**Moral:** Whether or not a process is strong Markov, as in (1), depends on which kernel we use. To me, this argues against using the transition function in the definition of *strong Markov*, and that we ought to use the following transition function-free version instead:
$$\mathbb{E}(f(X_{t+T}){\bf 1}_{(T<\infty)}\mid{\cal F}_T)=\mathbb{E}(f(X_{t+T}){\bf 1}_{(T<\infty)}\mid X_T).\tag2$$

Comment: It is a pity that we can not rely on the transition function, which is much more intuitive than the formal definition. I guess the founders of modern probability theory must have realized this kind of nuances when they adopted the less intuitive definition. Thank you so much, this is something really difficult for me to figure out by myself.

Comment: In many cases, e.g., for Feller processes, we do have a reasonable transition function and that we can use it to prove the strong Markov property. It's just when we start to explore boundary cases and look for counterexamples that this weird behaviour becomes noticeable.